# Access request for all user in SharePoint 2013 after claims-based authentication

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, claims-based-auth

After run this script, all user get access request:

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://ediyar "

$webApp.UseClaimsAuthentication = $True;

$webApp.Update()

$webapp.MigrateUsers($true)

$webApp.Update()

$webApp.ProvisionGlobally()
```

How to fix this?

Comment: What you want to fix? can you please explain it?

Comment: All user gets access request page. Site is not working outside server

Comment: Do you get the error message indicates that the user does not have access to the site? Or It is giving some other error?

Comment: Inside server able to access site with user login but outside its redirect to access request page. And here is the System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)), StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitWeb() at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_EnableMinimalDownload()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.RenderToBase(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)

Comment: Please read this article.... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/jj906556.aspx

Comment: Authentication Authorization   agb9s Medium   Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=False, UserIdentityName=, ClaimsCount=0 bac17a9d-fdcc-3002-3b48-608c155e535d
05/10/2016 12:10:46.75  w3wp.exe (0x11BC)                        0x2EC4 SharePoint Foundation          Claims Authentication           Verbose  Claims Windows Sign-In: Sending 401 for request 'http://myserver/Pages/Home.aspx' because the user is not authenticated and resource requires authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the problem.

Did you configure the Cache **SuperUser** and **SuperReader** Accounts?
It happens if they weren't configured.

Please follow steps in this MSDN article to configure those accounts for your SharePoint 2013 Environment.

[Configure object cache user accounts in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758656(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: Shall i use NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE  as super reader account?

Comment: You have to use specific account for both.

Comment: Now site not even up inside server. Access request page comes

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the object cache required 3 steps:

1. Add the super user and super reader account in Policy for web app.
2. Configure the both account for web application. In this, make sure if you are passing the account in claims format. like this

   $wa = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity ""

   $wa.Properties["portalsuperuseraccount"] = "i:0#.w|DOMAIN\SuperUA"

   $wa.Properties["portalsuperreaderaccount"] = "i:0#.w|DOMAIN\SuperRA"

   $wa.Update()

If no Claims then you will get the access denied.

3. Reset IIS on all servers.

If you want to do it via powershell, check this code:[SharePoint 2016 Object Cache Configuration farm wide with IIS reset](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/SharePoint-2016-Object-888ce77f)